# Change options of a pstricks node after it is printed

Tags: color, pstricks, pst-node

is there any possibility to change the options (for example color) of a printed node?
I create a lot of nodes with multido and want to change their appearance. Is there any way to do it after it got printed?

Background:
I want to plan biological experiments and color the circles (corresponding to a sample) in a different color like this:
[image]

MWE:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,multido,fp}
\begin{document}
\FPset{\AnzahlX}{6}
\FPset{\AnzahlY}{4}
\FPset{\AbstandX}{1.57}
\FPset{\AbstandY}{1.47}
\FPset{\Abstand}{1.88}
\FPset{\Durchmesser}{1.5}
\FPdiv\Radius\Durchmesser{2}
\begin{pspicture}(0.7,-0.7)(12.9,-8.7)%
    %Rahmen
    \pspolygon(0,0)(12.8,0)(12.8,-8.2)(12.4,-8.6)(0,-8.6)%
    %
    %Beschriftung
    \multido{\nX=\AbstandX+\Abstand,\iN=1+1}{\AnzahlX}{\rput(\nX,0.5){\iN}}%
    \multido{\nY=-\AbstandY+-\Abstand,\iC=65+1}{\AnzahlY}{\rput(-0.5,\nY){\char\iC}}%
    %
    %Wellplates
    \multido{\nY=-\AbstandY+-\Abstand,\iX=1+1}{\AnzahlY}{\multido{\nX=\AbstandX+\Abstand,\iY=1+1}{\AnzahlX}{\Cnode[radius=\Radius](\nX,\nY){\iX\iY}}}%
\end{pspicture}
Now I want to change color from red to light red for Well A1 to A5
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change it afterwards? Wouldn't it be more efficient (and possible) to do it while creating the circles?

Comment: Werner gave me a good idea. This works, but is somewhat a lot defining. In my mind was something like \mycommand{Row1}{StartColor}{EndColor}, as I want to set different colors to different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the node names for the coordinates and define a color series with 6 steps:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\begin{document}
\def\AnzahlX{6}
\def\AnzahlY{4}
\def\AbstandX{1.57}
\def\AbstandY{1.47}
\def\Abstand{1.88}
\def\Durchmesser{1.5}
\pstFPdiv\Radius\Durchmesser{2}

\definecolorseries{foo}{rgb}{last}{red}{red!30!white}
\resetcolorseries[6]{foo}

\begin{pspicture}(0.7,-0.7)(12.9,-8.7)%
%Rahmen
\pspolygon(0,0)(12.8,0)(12.8,-8.2)(12.4,-8.6)(0,-8.6)%
%
%Beschriftung
\multido{\nX=\AbstandX+\Abstand,\iN=1+1}{\AnzahlX}{\rput(\nX,0.5){\iN}}%
\multido{\nY=-\AbstandY+-\Abstand,\iC=65+1}{\AnzahlY}{\rput(-0.5,\nY){\char\iC}}%
    %
%Wellplates
\multido{\nY=-\AbstandY+-\Abstand,\iX=1+1}{\AnzahlY}{%
    \multido{\nX=\AbstandX+\Abstand,\iY=1+1}{\AnzahlX}{%
        \Cnode[radius=\Radius](\nX,\nY){N\iX\iY}}}%
%Now I want to change color from red to light red for Well A1 to A5
\multido{\iA=1+1}{\AnzahlX}{%
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=foo!!+](N1\iA){\Radius}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert, this is something i can use to do a easy command for adding color to the wells.

Comment: Is there a command like \stepcolorseries that does just step through the colorseries?

Comment: As far as I know yes, but you have to read the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Specific to your example of changing the colours for A1 through A6 in a sequential manner, you can add options like for filling the nodes with a specific colour. Below I've added `fillstyle=solid` to ensure that the first row is filled and `fillcolor=red!<C>!lightred` be the fill colour; `<C>` measures the share of colour between `red` and `lightred` (defined as a mixture of `red` and `white`) which decreases from 100% `red` to (almost) 100% `lightred` in the last circle.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node,multido,fp}

\begin{document}

\FPset{\AnzahlX}{6}
\FPset{\AnzahlY}{4}
\FPset{\AbstandX}{1.57}
\FPset{\AbstandY}{1.47}
\FPset{\Abstand}{1.88}
\FPset{\Durchmesser}{1.5}
\FPdiv\Radius\Durchmesser{2}

\colorlet{lightred}{red!30!white}

\begin{pspicture}(0.7,-0.7)(12.9,-8.7)%
  %Rahmen
  \pspolygon(0,0)(12.8,0)(12.8,-8.2)(12.4,-8.6)(0,-8.6)%
  %Beschriftung
  \multido{\nX=\AbstandX+\Abstand,\iN=1+1}{\AnzahlX}{\rput(\nX,0.5){\iN}}%
  \multido{\nY=-\AbstandY+-\Abstand,\iC=65+1}{\AnzahlY}{\rput(-0.5,\nY){\char\iC}}%
  %Wellplates
  \multido{\nY=-\AbstandY+-\Abstand,\iX=1+1}{\AnzahlY}
    {\multido{\nX=\AbstandX+\Abstand,\iY=1+1,\iC=100+-16}{\AnzahlX}
      {\ifnum\iX=1
         \Cnode[radius=\Radius,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!\iC!lightred](\nX,\nY){\iX\iY}
       \else
         \Cnode[radius=\Radius](\nX,\nY){\iX\iY}
       \fi
      }
    }%
\end{pspicture}

Now I want to change color from red to light red for Well A1 to A6

\end{document}
```